# Designing a simple console trivia application

Tags: c#, random, user-input

We have been tasked with designing a C# trivia application as a File I/O exercise. So far, I've got a good start, but the presentation step is kind of stumping me.

I'm starting with a delimited file featuring the following data:

```
Question;CorrectAnswerA;AnswerB;AnswerC;AnswerD;AnswerExplanation
```

e.g.,

```
 What color is the sky?;Blue;White;Green;Yellow;The sky is blue.
```

The game will display the question and the four answers from which the user can select.

```
What Color is the Sky?
A. Blue
B. White
C. Green
D. Yellow

Select A, B, C, or D:
```

Unfortunately, for ease of populating the dataset, `A` is always the correct answer. I want to randomize the order in which the four answers display, but the program still needs to know which was the correct answer. I also need to have a user input of `A`, `B`, `C`, or `D` tie back to a specific instance of an answer to compare the `selectedAnswerString` to the `correctAnswerString`.

I've been playing with an array of the four answers which are randomly populated, but I can't wrap my head around how to flag something as correct based on the user's choice; my logic to do or assign that always seems to fall out of scope or duplicate across all four records in the array.

Other students I've talked to said they created their datasets with the answers pre-scrambled (so they can just print them in the order read) with a FIFTH answer field for the correct answer. While definitely an EASY way to make it happen, I don't think it's as elegant as my strategy.

Should I just change the input dataset? does anyone have any ideas on a good way to pursue my idea for the randomization?

Answer (score 1):

Create a class called `Question` with properties: `int Id`, `string QuestionText`, `List<string> Answers`, `string CorrectAnswer`

Or, as step forward, also create class `Answer` with `Id` and `Value` and reference to it.

```
   public class Question
    {
        public int Id;
        public string QuestionText;
        public List<Answer> Answers;
        public Answer CorrectAnswer;
    }

    public class Answer
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Value;
    }
```

Afterwards populate this structure and randomize when printing

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the correct answer using a separate variable. Then use [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to shuffle your array:

```
Random random = new Random();

void Shuffle(string[] answers) {
   for (int i = 0; i < answers.Length - 1; i++) {
      int j = random.Next(i, answers.Length);
      string temp = answers[j];
      answers[j] = answers[i];
      answers[i] = temp;
   }
}
```

After the user responds, just compare their selection with the correct answer you've saved.

Comment: And how do I keep track of the user's selection and the answer? Is `switch` the best way to manage `A` is `answers[1]`, `B` is `answers[2]` etc.? or is there a better strategy?

Comment: @dwwilson66 That's fine, although you need to remember the arrays are indexed starting from zero. You can use `answers[selectedChar - 'A']`, which will give you `A = 0, B = 1, ...`.

Comment: it's early...no coffee yet. :) I knew that.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your data structure for a question in this way:

```
public class Question
{
    public string Question;
    public string[] Answers;
    public int CorrectAnswer;
    public string CorrectAnswerExplanation
}
```

This way you can scramble the strings in the array `Answers`, while still keeping track of the index of the correct answer in `CorrectAnswer`.

Alternatively if you can't use a separate class to model the question (this is a homework question so maybe you have not learned this yet), you can use a predetermined position in the array (the 1st or the 5th element) to hold the index of the correct answer. So your array for answers would look like:

```
"Blue", "White", "Green", "Yellow", "0"
```

Comment: we've learned how to use separate classes...but all the other students I'm talking to are using a field in their dataset to hold a correct answer marker. Personally, I think that defeats the purpose of reusability and I'm trying to avoid hardcoding anything that can be determined programatically. My instructor and I have been butting heads all semester on how generic an object or data structure needs to or should be. But that's a topic for the interpersonal-relations-overflow.com. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Define a data structure. Others have already given you a structure so use that.

Step 2: Populate your data structure. You could System.IO.File.ReadLines and parse each line - I assume you have this bit handled already.

Step 3: Randomize the order of your answers. For this, assuming you have your structure:

```
public static void RandomiseAnswers(IEnumerable<Question> questions)
{
    var rand = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    foreach (var question in questions) 
    {
        question.Answers = question.Answers.OrderBy(x => rand.Next()).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Step 4: Recieve gold star from teacher for your outstanding work

Comment: I wish. She's the type that docks points for adding a method to the UML we're given. But I like this...just to mess with her. One question I did have about this line: `var rand = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);` Is it randomizing using current time as a seed? I'm not familiar with the `.Ticks` piece of it, and am off to look at the on MSDN right now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd put a boolean in the Answer class defaulting to false.  This way when the answer is selected you can read whether it's correct or not.

```
public class AskQuestion
{
    public int Id;
    public string Question;
    public string Explanation;
    public List<Answer> Answers = new List<Answer>();
}

public class Answer
{
    public bool Correct = false;
    public string Value;
}
```

now when you randomize the list the correct answer is automatically identified

One way to use these classes would be like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("text.txt");
        List<AskQuestion> Questions = new List<AskQuestion>();
        Random rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        //Loop through the file building a list of questions
        while(!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            AskQuestion NewQuestion = new AskQuestion();
            string[] input = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');
            NewQuestion.Question = input[0];
            NewQuestion.Explanation = input[5];
            for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Answer NewAnswer = new Answer();
                NewAnswer.Value = input[i];
                NewQuestion.Answers.Add(NewAnswer);
            }
            //The first question is always correct so set its boolean value to true;
            NewQuestion.Answers[0].Correct = true;
            //Now ranmdomize the order of the answers
            NewQuestion.Answers = NewQuestion.Answers.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToList();
            Questions.Add(NewQuestion);
        }
        //Generate menu and get response for each question
        foreach(AskQuestion q in Questions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(q.Question + ":\n\tA - " + q.Answers[0].Value + "\n\tB - " + q.Answers[1].Value + "\n\tC - " + q.Answers[2].Value + "\n\tD - " + q.Answers[3].Value + "\n");
            char input = '0';
            while(input < 'A' || input > 'D')
            {
                input = char.ToUpper(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar);
                if(input >= 'A' && input <= 'D')
                {
                    //Use the boolean value in the answer to test for correctness.
                    if(q.Answers[input - 'A'].Correct)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nCorrect\n");
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("\nWrong\n");

                    Console.WriteLine(q.Explanation);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: then such answers cannot be re-usable among different questions.

Comment: Each question has its own list of answers.  Re-using the answers for a different question doesn't make much sense.  Each instance of the class will have its own string and boolean.

Comment: "its own list of answers" - true, but "list of unique answers" - not necessary, as there may be "True/False" questions or questions like "2^3=" or "how much bits in Byte", etc.. It is not necessity, but a probability and in this case it will be wiser to re-use already existent answers than to create new duplicates

Comment: If it's desirable to re-use the AskQuestion object and change the values that can easily be done.  Nothing in that code would preclude that.  Just change the values.

Comment: `in this case it will be wiser to re-use already existent answers than to create new duplicates`  So what you're saying is, get the questions and answers from a data source and loop through all the previous answers to find a duplicate and re-use it instead of creating a new one with duplicate values.  That doesn't make any sense.